# Architecture recommendation for large class?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a class right now with the following shell:

```
class Chapter {
    ...

    public function chapter_001(){}
    public function chapter_002(){}
    public function chapter_003(){}
    ...
}
```

Ordinarily, the method would just be `chapter` (without the `_xxx`) and a parameter to know which to query for, but in this case each method runs quite a bit of code that varies the output based on the spec, each independent from the last save for a couple private methods and a configuration object in the constructor.

Worse yet, I wind up calling the right method via some not so tasty code:

```
if (method_exists($chapter, "chapter_" . $id)) {
    // Do things
}
```

Is there a better way to structure something like this?

Comment: Without knowning what the code is about, it is very difficult to make an useful suggestion. Clearly numbering your methods is not the way to go.

Comment: For a bit more context: in a nutshell, each chapter outputs anywhere from one to a few paragraphs of text, dynamically generated based on the config object generated in the constructor and the contents of a few API calls. Each method called sequentially has the ability to tell a unique story each time it's run.

Comment: It still seems to me that your whole approach to object oriented programming (OOP) is flawed. Your architecture is based on the output, and not on what the objects and methods actually do. A result of using your methods might be this sequential output, but it should not be the basis of your OOP architecture. Sorry, I'm making a lot of assumptions here. I still have no idea what your code is about.